# Why mention God, our god, for the chatas/asham and not for the ola/sh'lamim/toda?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, nusach-sefard, korbanos-ketores-prayers

*Sidurim* (such as [*Rav Yaakov* Emden's](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42759&pgnum=79), but also modern *nusach S'farad* ones like ArtScroll's and *T'filas Kol Pe*) include a short prayer after various of the paragraphs of "*Ezehu m'koman*" asking God to consider the recitation of the paragraph as if the person praying had offered the sacrificial offering discussed in the paragraph. But the wording differs for different paragraphs: Why do we have "May it be your will, God, our and our fathers' god" for *chatas* and *asham* and just "May it be [your] will", with no mention of God, for *ola*, *sh'lamim*, and *toda*?

Comment: The Hirsch siddur, Artscroll, and Koren all translate the second God with a capital G. Our God and God of our fathers.

Comment: @user6591 Thanks for letting me know. IMO I don't need to follow suit in this post.

Answer (score 2):

I once heard - do not remember from whom - that we say Hashem's name at the Korbanos that are done for a personal Kapara such as a Chatas and Asham to invoke Hashem's mercy upon us.

Comment: Olah gives personal kapara too. In viduy on yom kippur we mention it.